# Mac Mini 2.1 (32bit EFI / 64bit CPU) Ubuntu 18.04.2 Server - GRUB reports unknown filesystem

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, mac-mini

All the instructions I can find only deal with Ubuntu 16.04 and older. So my steps are probably wrong for 18.04 - for now I'm using the instructions found here: https://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/

Fresh download Ubuntu 18.04.2 Server. 
used rufus to make USB from ISO. 
put bootia32.efi in EFI/boot on USB. 
Boot the MacMini from USB using ALT key. 
Choose EFI and continue. So far so good.

Comes up to GRUB menu and select install Ubuntu server. 
Run installer with all defaults (no extra packages) but with openSSH. 
Format the internal drive guided: use entire disk.

Everything seems to go well. It shows an efiboot partition and an ext4 partition.

I understood the instructions said this will not be bootable yet.

ok, so reboot into grub console. `ls` shows `(hd0) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (cd0) error: failure reading sector 0x0 of 'cd0'`
I think that would be the CD drive because (hd0) is usb install and (hd1,gpt1) has an efi directory. however `ls (hd1,gpt2)` says `error: unknown filesystem`.

`ls -l` doesn't work. say `illegal argument` so now I'm stuck. from the steps in the instructions I need to find uuid but how?

UPDATE: I made a Ubuntu 18.04 desktop USB and booted in live mode. `fsck /dev/sda2` reported no errors. However, i am not familiar with unix commands and don't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

I got 18.04 running on one of these a couple years ago, and it runs really nicely. It was definitely a hassle on this model, but once installed it seems smooth as silk. Unfortunately, I didn't really keep notes, so I don't know the answers to your questions off the top of my head...but I can probably help you figure it out if you're still stuck. (I see it's been a couple years, so I'll hold off unless you request more info!)

Right now I'm running an upgrade to 20.04, fingers crossed! It's going to become my home file server. (USB 2.0 is an unfortunate limitation, but I think it'll be fine for personal use.)